# Related Lists missing from Metadata Layout

Tags: metadata-api, page-layout, related-list

I am using the FinancialForce Metadata API to retrieve a Layout of an object Foo.

For some reason, the object that I am getting back is missing items in its RelatedListItem[] array.

I have a Related List present in my layout visually in the Salesforce GUI, yet the Metadata call comes back with a null array.

Stranger yet, it only seems to happen to this object. Placing the same Related List on object Bar's layout and querying it using Metadata API yields a correct array.

What is happening and how can I fix this?

Edit: my user has full system privileges

Comment: For comparison you could try using Ant (Force Migration Tool) or Eclipse to retrieve the Layout and see if the RelatedListItem items are in the result. If the items are missing there as well then there may be an issue with Salesforce.

Comment: Just to be clear, what do you mean by "FinacialForce Metadata API"? Are you referring to [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) or [Salesforce Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm)

Comment: The first one, the Apex wrapper for Metadata API.